# Какой запрос быстрее?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
"SELECT * FROM `zzz` WHERE `ip` = '".$this->ip."';"
$numbers = mysql_num_rows($cat);
```

или

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `zzz` WHERE `ip` = '".$this->ip."';"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очевидно, что второй.
Если условия нет, то этот запрос вообще очень быстрый. Если по полям, которым есть индекс - чуть медленее, но все равно очень быстрый.

С другой стороны, вызов `mysql_num_rows($cat);` может потребовать передачу большого кол-ва данных, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` знает, что это будет одно число (MySQL имеет специальные оптимизации на этот случай).

Поэтому, при равных частях условия, второй запрос точно будет не медленее, а в большинстве случаев заметно быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `zzz` WHERE `ip` = '".$this->ip."'");
$numbers = mysql_result($cat, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Время выполнения будет одинаковым, *если мы говорим об SQL*, т.к. СУБД и для того, и для другого выбирает одно и то же количество записей!

Comment: Это не всегда так. Если нет условия, то это будет очень быстро, так как мускуль хранит количество строк в таблице.
Если по полю есть индекс, и база сможет его использовать, то опять же, даже смотреть в таблицу не нужно.

Но с другими базами может быть по другому.

Comment: @KoVadim, к топику это отношения не имеет -- там есть условие. А по индексу всё равно нужно пройти, чтобы подсчитать количество записей.

Comment: @orkaan не надо хитрить. В одном случае -- просто посчитать, а другом (если разработчики решили "сделать оптимизацию" -- сохранить внутри СУБД список найденных)

Comment: @orkaan

Нужно понимать, что такое индекс. И почему пройтись по индексу иногда просто в десятки-сотни раз быстрее. Даже если есть индексы. Приведу простой пример. Пусть есть столбик, в котором будут целые числа в диапазоне 1.100. А строк к примеру несколько миллионов. А нужно найти те, которые больше 50.
Без индексов нужно пробежать по всем строкам и считать. А в случае индексов все интереснее - есть бинарный файл, в котором записи вида "1" в 3,4 и 100 строке, "2" - в 400..1000 и так далее. Получается, что нужно просуммировать не более 50 строк. Что очень  быстрее предыдущего.

Comment: @KoVadim, всё верно! Только и `select *...`, и `select count(*)...` будут выполняться одинаково, т.к. оба будут использовать **один и тот же индекс**.
@alexlz, наверное, результат `count` и выборки хранится в разных местах? :-)
Теоретикам, привет! Вы бы хоть __план запроса__ посмотрели, что ли, где наглядно видно, что при наличии `count` в запросе в план добавляется аггрегация!

Comment: в случае наличия `count(*)`, мускуль знает, что данные не нужно возвращать. А только одно значение. И хотя обрабатываться запросы будут одинаково (но не всегда), но возвращать значение будет быстрее, плюс серверу даже не нужно думать о выделении памяти под результаты.

Comment: @orkaan, для выполнения select * после поиска по индексу необходимо пойти в основную таблицу и по номерам записей, полученным из индекса, выгрести всю информацию!